# Enable/Show pop-up windows from UIWebView?

Tags: swift, uiwebview, webkit, popupwindow

I am loading a URL in a UIWebView. Upon loading the URL it should prompt for credentials in a pop-up window. But in UIWebView pop-up windows are not working. Can someone help me implement the same?

Comment: Have you tried using `WKWebView` instead? From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview): "Starting in iOS 8.0 and OS X 10.10, use WKWebView to add web content to your app. Do not use UIWebView or WebView."

Comment: @Paolo does it support showing pop-ups?

Comment: Yes with this delegate method: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455638-webview (specifically the `URLAuthenticationChallenge`)